# Azure devops repo not updating when a change is made to github repo

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops

So recently I was following this tutorial

https://youtu.be/aMO-NQ1Xza0?t=848 (This is a short little part ~30 seconds)

Till I got to this part and I have been stuck ever since.

I am completely unable to update the repo past the first time it is deployed. It doesn't matter how it is pushed (Through console or VScode). It simply will not push to the devOps repo like it does in the video. Maybe I am missing something.

I did find an extremely janky way of doing this by taking cloning the azure repo into another folder and copying and pasting any changes from the github into that folder.

Here is an example of what happens when I push to github

Recent push in github

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebFhj.png

The push wasn't recognized by the devops branch

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH2FE.png

Comment: if you use a github-repo instead of an azuredevops-repo you can update the source of your build to use the github-repo and its ci-triggers

Comment: you probably misunderstand something, git push works just fine with ADO